# How are these equations equal?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, algorithms, summation

I am reading CLRS 3rd edition([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)) on page `26`, author deduced a formula for the `running time` of `insertion sort` and that is:
[image]

Then author explains that above formula is equal to following when t<sub>j</sub>=1
[image]

Can anyone explain how are these equations equal, especially the terms having c<sub>5</sub> and c<sub>6</sub>? Also why c<sub>6</sub> is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $t_j$ is $1$ for all $j$, then $\sum_{j=2}^{n}{(t_j - 1)} = 0$, thus $c_6$ and $c_7$ cancel out, and $\sum_{j=2}^{n}{t_j} = \sum_{j=2}^{n}{1} = n - 1$.

Therefore, you obtain the desired formula.

**Edit (more details):**
Assume $t_j$ = 1 for all $j$,

$$ c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5\sum_{j=2}^{n}{t_j} + c_6\sum_{j=2}^{n}{(t_j - 1)} + c_7\sum_{j=2}^{n}{(t_j - 1)} + c_8(n-1)$$
$$  c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5\sum_{j=2}^{n}{1} + c_6\sum_{j=2}^{n}{(1 - 1)} + c_7\sum_{j=2}^{n}{(1 - 1)} + c_8(n-1) $$
$$  c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5\sum_{j=2}^{n}{1} + c_6\sum_{j=2}^{n}{0} + c_7\sum_{j=2}^{n}{0} + c_8(n-1) $$
$$  c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5(n-1) + 0 + 0 + c_8(n-1) $$
$$  c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5(n-1) + c_8(n-1) $$
$$  (c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8)n - (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8) $$

Comment: What about term having c5? How did it get (n-1)?

Comment: @user3461957, I have added details. Is it clear now?