# How $\sum_{j=2}^{n}{1}$ is equal to `n−1` in this example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1390697/139017) is the example I am talking about.

Comment: Try plugging in a value of $n$ between, say, $2$ and $10$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{n}{1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{1}-1=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}}-1=n-1.
$$

Comment: Crystal clear..

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no idea why someone would struggle with this, but here goes.

$\sum_{j=2}^21 =1=(2-1)$

Assume it is true for a certain $k$. Then,

$\sum_{j=2}^{k+1} 1=\sum_{j=2}^k1+\sum_{j=k}^{k+1}1 =(k-1)+1=(k+1)-1$

Thus, by induction, it holds for all $n\geq2$. QED.

Comment: I really doubt the OP was looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Well, if he couldn't see it naturally as in Oliver's answer, I thought a rigorous proof should clear things up. Oh well, maybe not everyone thinks the same. :p

Answer (score 0):

$1$ does not depend on $j$, so when $j=2$ you have $1$, for $j=3$ you add another $1$, and so on. How many $1$s do you add? Well, how many numbers are there from $2$ to $n$?